# How to redirect traffic/packets on one port to another port or server:port?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, proxy, port-forwarding

I found similar questions but couldn't get them to work for my use case. I have a linux server running memcached that is listening to traffic on its local network ip, which is on `eth1`. I would like to allow a specific external IP to access memcached (has to be specific as there is no auth on memcached, and I don't want to restart the service and lose the cache.)

So I would like to do two things:

1. On the memcached server, allow a specific external IP "A" to connect to the server on `eth0`, the public net, and forward the packets to eth0 with access to memcached. **There should be no interference with existing traffic to memcached on `eth1`.** This can probably be done with iptables.
2. Use the server with IP "A" as a proxy for other servers on its LAN. How can I set up all traffic on "A":1234 to forward to `eth0` on the memcached server? Can this be done with iptables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could probably do this with iptables, but I think this would be easier to maintain as a userspace layer 4 proxy (haproxy can be configured to work this way; lots of good guides on Google to be found).

Comment: @DrewBloechl you're probably referring to point 2. Surely point 1 is pretty straight-forward for iptables?

Comment: Yes, my previous comment is about point 2. For point 1, I think what you want is a DNAT rule.